# Disabled Orchard Module (feature) / Entire site is broken

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

I was trying to make changes to a module.  I couldn't get the site to seem to reflect those changes.  I thought I could possibly disable the feature, and re-enable the feature and it would force whatever module caching is happening to reload the module.  However, it broke the site entirely, and now I can't even enable the feature from the orchard.exe command line tool.  I am getting the same error.  It's basically Autofac complaining that it can't find a type that was part of the feature.  However, if the feature is removed, I am not sure where/why it is still trying to load.

Exception :

```
None of the constructors found with 'Orchard.Environment.AutofacUtil.DynamicProxy2.ConstructorFinderWrapper' on type 'RCAM.Products.Drivers.FeaturedProductsWidgetPartDriver' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'RCAM.Products.Services.IProductService productService' of constructor 'Void .ctor(RCAM.Products.Services.IProductService)'.
```

I cannot get in the admin portal to re-enable the feature.  I cannot use the command line tool.  I tried setting the [Settings_ShellFeatureStateRecord] to Up in the database, but that didn't change anything at all.  It must be file driven as well as database persisted.

This is a production site and is currently down.  Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should never, ever make changes to code in production. If your change prevents the module from compiling (as is the case here), it will bring the whole site down. To get unblocked, make a copy of your changes, then delete the module's directory. The site should now work, minus that module's features. Fix it on a dev machine, then deploy that working version.

Comment: Bertrand.  Thanks for the advice.  It did compile on my local dev machine, and the code change worked as expected locally.  My assumption was that I could copy/overwrite the new module binaries in the module/bin folder on the production server, and it would instantly reflect those changes, the same way it does in a normal MVC application.  It didn't, even after recycling the app pool.  The error you see above only appeared, and immediately occurred, after I disabled the feature in the admin portal.

Comment: Deploying by partial file copy can fail in lots of different subtle ways. Dynamic compilation may be on or off on the target, your app_data/Dependencies may need to be deleted, etc. It's usually a good idea to publish or build precompiled before deploying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't make it clear if you changed the code directly on your production site or if it crashed after a proper deployment, so here are my two cents:

If you make changes to your module in a live environment you should delete the contents of your **App_Data/Dependencies**-Folder afterwards. No need to re-enable the module.

This will only work, if you haven't disabled the [Dynamic Module loader](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Orchard-module-loader-and-dynamic-compilation/), which should be done though in a production environment.

---

Otherwise, make sure your module actually compiles. You should probably add your Module to **Orchard.Web**s build dependencies to make sure it actually re-compiles every time you run Orchard on your dev machine.

For removing the feature, instead of just disabling it, it should be enough remove your module folder and delete **YourModule.dll** from **App_Data/Dependencies**

Comment: I am marking this as correct because I didn't realize I could delete the App_Data/Dependencies folder and it would rebuild dynamically.  Thanks